# How to properly get csv file header in c#? Getting different results for same code

Tags: c#, csv, filereader

I'm wanting to extract header data (to be clear: I mean the first row of the file which contains the column names) from a csv file (I've seen from other posts that FileHelpers is supposed to be good, but in my case it isn't an option...) and it works, but i still have problems with it.

I'm wanting to read a file with the following format (sorry for bad formatting, i wouldn't know how to make it prettier here):

```
header1,header2,header3
data1,data2,data3
```

I'm using following code to achieve this:

```
string [] csvHeader;
using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(file.OpenText(), true, ','))
{
   if (!csv.GetFieldHeaders().Any())
       throw new Exception("header of file empty \n" + file.FullName);
                                    
   csvHeader = csv.GetFieldHeaders()[0].ToString().Split(',');
   if (!CompareArrays(csvHeader, expHeaderFormat))
       throw new MalformedCsvException("Csv Headers don't match! \n CsvHeader: " + csvHeader.ToString() + "\n Expected format: " + expHeaderFormat.ToString());
}
```

Now to my question:

1. Why do i need to get the first element "[0]" when retrieving the headers? This doesn't make sense to me.
2. 1. only works for one file for me, when trying it on another file, which is formatted exactly the same (in my opinion), all of a suddon, when i access [0] i get the first element of the header. This is the behaviour i'd expect but now i can't read out the entire header for some reason.
3. Why can't one just do the following to retrieve the entire first row, because according to the documentation "GetFieldHeaders()" returns an array of strings, so it would make sense for me:

   ```
   csvHeader =csv.GetFieldHeaders().ToString().Split(',');
   ```

I Hope that enough to go on to grasp my problem...

Edit: I am using following libaries

```
using CsvFile;
using LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv;
```

Comment: Do you want an array or string?

Comment: I'm trying to save the header fields into my string array

Comment: `csvHeader = csv.GetFieldHeaders();` ? I am not sure what library you are using, however it would make sense that the `GetFieldHeaders` method returns a list or an array or something. just assign it, if its some other sort of `IEnumerable` Call `.GetFieldHeaders().ToArray()`

Comment: Yes, that is what i thought also, but when i assign `csvHeader = csv.GetFieldHeaders();` it saves the entire first csv row into the first element of my array, which doesn't make sense...

Comment: Where is the documentation for this library you are using?

Comment: i was reading this documentation: https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/CsvReader/GetFieldHeaders/php-csvreader-getfieldheaders-method-examples.html

Comment: My guess is this library is looking for a different delimitator other than `,`. maybe you should try the CsvHelper, library, at least its easy to find the documentation for it

Comment: It works now...i don't understand the behavious but with the first file i needed to do `csvHeader = csv.GetFieldHeaders()[0].ToString().Split(',');`and the second needed to be read, as you said with just 'csvHeader = csv.GetFieldHeaders();

Will look into the CsvHelper library, thank you a lot!

Comment: You did not set the proper delimeter. The first file has , as delimiter... The second has ; ... Your splitting should never happen. You circumvent the purpose of a csv reader.

Comment: @LegacyCode Where do i split it with ";"? I don't quite follow

Comment: You should not even use split... That’s the point. The CsvReader have a delimiter which you should have set. The part where you have to grab the first item in an array is a hint that something is wrong. The CsvReader was not able to read the csv file properly. Aaand thats because the delimiter is not properly set.

Comment: new CsvReader(file.OpenText(), true, ',') ... I assume the ‘,’ is the delimiter.... If you set it to ‘;’ then you will be able to read the file properly and don’t need the split misuse.

Comment: Oh that is what you mean, thank you for clarifying!

Answer (score 1):

The [codeproject docs for Lumenworks Csv](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader) note that the library is old now, but it should still work with the example code there:

```
using System.IO;
using LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv;
void ReadCsv()
{
    // open the file "data.csv" which is a CSV file with headers
    using (CsvReader csv =
           new CsvReader(new StreamReader("data.csv"), true))
    {
        int fieldCount = csv.FieldCount;

        string[] headers = csv.GetFieldHeaders();
        while (csv.ReadNextRecord())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++)
                Console.Write(string.Format("{0} = {1};",
                              headers[i], csv[i]));
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

> Why do i need to get the first element "[0]" when retrieving the headers? This doesn't make sense to me.

There is some chatter in the comments about how the entire first line of the file is coming into array 0. I'm not sure how this is possible because:

- you have pasted an example of your file into the question, and it truly contains commas
- csv stands for comma separated value
- csv reader uses comma as a splitter by default

The only ways I foresee a csv reader not splitting your first line on the commas are:

- the first line starts with " or other quote character and is hence being treated as a single value -> the file is corrupt, fix the file or change the quote character used by the reader
- the file doesn't use true ascii commas as the separator but maybe uses some other Unicode character that looks like a comma; fix the file or specify the actual separator to the reader
- the reader library doesn't split on commas by default (hard to believe) so specify the comma in the constructor of csv reader, after the True

> only works for one file for me, when trying it on another file, which is formatted exactly the same (in my opinion), all of a suddon, when i access [0] i get the first element of the header. This is the behaviour i'd expect but now i can't read out the entire header for some reason.

You need to show us screenshots of these files, open in a hex editor, so we can tell you. It will be one of the reasons I give above. Right now all we've got is your word that the files look the same to you; show us true files so we can make this assessment independently

You complain that you can't get all the headers but you never will if you only select the first one with [0] - the library is returning all, you're choosing to remember only one and throwing the rest away

You're doing weird debug code, comparing arrays etc, that you don't need to; all that inspection can be done in the debugger, using the code I posted above *which was written by the person who wrote the library - it is correct*.

You're pulling scraps of code off some example site which are codes written by different people with different scenarios and not guaranteed to be equivalent to your scenario - they might be splitting on tabs, or have weird quote chars etc. You can't see the files they're reading, only the code they wrote. We should dispense with all that and look at the files you are reading and make this fit your scenario, not theirs

> Why can't one just do the following to retrieve the entire first row, because according to the documentation "GetFieldHeaders()" returns an array of strings, so it would make sense for me:

> csvHeader =csv.GetFieldHeaders().ToString().Split(',');

Because that will never ever work in a month of Sundays. GetFieldHeaders returns an array of strings that are the headers. Calling ToString on an array of strings gives the type of the object, which in this case is "System.String[]", which contains no headers and no commas, so splitting it on comma is completely useless and the wrong thing to do!

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer and for pointing out, that the library is somewhat outdated! I will try to update the question and try your suggestions on Monday when I have my company laptop again.

True, without further info you need to take my word that the files are in same format. Will try to update it!

The part of adding the ',' as a delimiter in the constructor I do already and I'm fairly sure the other bug points aren't the case either but will only know after double checking again.

Comment: No probs; don't forget to post us a screenshot of the csv file open in a *hex* editor such as HxD. I usually ask for hex dumps of files because they show up invisible things like byte order marks and other things that can confuse parsers - you don't necessarily see these things if you open a csv in e.g. notepad and paste what you see; a screenshot of a hex editor is truly a warts n all way of looking at the data and we can use it in conjunction with lumenworks' code so see if anything is going wonky